# How to convert the column number format of a excel sheet in c# dynamically?

Tags: c#, excel, string-formatting

I am exporting some fields to an excel sheet in c#. All but one column are coming correctly, but in that column I need to export the value 0 to 0.00 format.

When my code behind code is running I am appending the value to a stringBuilder object as 0.00 format, but when I opened that exported document it shows the value as 0. Then I must change the column number format in the excel sheet and change the number format by selecting the type 12.3323.

I don't want to do it like this. I want to define the column number format dynamically in c# code behind file.

How can I do this? Please suggest me if you know.

Comment: How are you exporting? Are you using the Excel .NET library? Some other library? Or just CSV or HTML export?

Comment: You have to be aware that 0 and 0.0 and 0.00 is the same value. The value and the format are two different things. My impression is, that you try to define the format by choosing a different value (which happens to be the same value). But I don't know how to define the excel format with dot.net.

Answer (score 0):

I think C# does right what it does. The issue is that you need to specify the "column format" in excel in order for it to show that way. Just add the format mask.

Comment: i asked you to give the another way which i can do it with code , your answer doesn't match with my requirement thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You can use Format function to convert your value when writing into cell.
Like :

```
Format(Convert.ToDouble(data.ToString()), "0.00")
```

Comment: i said that i am inserting correct value only to cell but the excel sheet is showing that number in its default format , i want to give that cell number format dynamically in c#

Comment: have you set the type of data to Float when inserting data to cell?
if you writing by xml then you can do it as :
<ss:Cell ss:StyleID=""{1}""><ss:Data ss:Type=""Float"">

Comment: post sample code here so that we can get exact idea about your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Range.NumberFormat = "0.00"` (English version) or `"0,00"` (for the German version of Office);
e.g. `ws.get_Range("A1", "C2").NumberFormat = "0.00";`